# Filter specific numbers from multiple files

Tags: awk, r

I have multiple files (apx. 150) that look like this:

```
reconstructed_hap_4_Local_nt_haplo_freq_60.3 GGGCAACTGGGCCAAGGTCGCTATCATCATGGTTATGTTTTCAGGGGTCGATGCCAATACATATATCACCGGTGGCAAAGCAGCTCAAACTGCCAGAGGCCTTGTTGGCTGGTTTAATCCGGGTCCCAAACAGAACCTGCAGCTGGTCAACACCAATGGCTCGTGGCA
reconstructed_hap_6_Local_nt_haplo_freq_37.2 GGGCAACTGGGCCAAGGTCGCTATCATCATGGTTATGTTTTCAGGGGTCGATGCCGAAACATATGCCTCCGGTGGCAGTGCAGCTCGTAATACCTG-GGCCTTTCTAGCTTGTTTAGTTCGGGTCCCAAACAGAGCCTGCAGCTGGTCAACACCAATGGCTCGTGGCA
reconstructed_hap_1_Local_nt_haplo_freq_0.6 GGGCAACTGGGCCAAGGTCGCTATCATCATGGTTATGTTTTCAGGGGTCGATGCCAATACATATATCACCGGTGGCAAAGCAGCTCAAACTGCCAGAGGCCTTGTTTGGCTGTTTAATCCGGGTCCCAAACAGAACCTGCAGCTGGTCAACACCAATGGCTCGTGGCA
```

Each file has different number of lines.

I would like to filter from each files numbers from title line after "freq_"

In this example, I would like to filter: 60.3, 37.2, 0.6

The most preferred output should be a CSV file having each sample name

```
Filename1   60.3    37.2    0.6 
Filename2   56.1    26.2    52.3    42.1
Filename3   2.5     1.2
```

Do you have any solutions?

Comment: Sorry, I've made a mistake. It should be one word. I edited it.

Comment: again... what does `Filename1 ` mean?

Comment: name of first file.

Comment: What is a _title line_? How we detect them?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
cd /path/to/directory
for i in `ls`
do
        VALUE=`awk '{print $1}' $i | awk -F '_' '{print $NF}' | tr '\n' '\t'`
        echo -e "$i\t$VALUE" 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Awk:

```
awk '
  BEGINFILE {i=0} 
  {
    n=split($1,a,"_")
    freqs[i++] = a[n]
  } 
  ENDFILE {
    printf FILENAME
    for (j=0;j<i;j++) printf("\t%s", freqs[j])
    printf "\n"
    delete freqs
  }
' Filename*
```

Ex.

```
$ awk 'BEGINFILE{i=0;} {n=split($1,a,"_"); freqs[i++] = a[n]} ENDFILE{printf FILENAME; for (j=0;j<i;j++) printf("\t%s", freqs[j]); printf "\n"; delete freqs}' Filename*
Filename1   60.3    37.2    0.6
Filename2   56.1    26.2    52.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Shell Script:

```
for file_number in {1..150}
do
        data=$( cat file${file_number}.txt | cut -f1 -d' ' | cut -f8 -d'_' | tr '\n' '\t' )
        #echo $data
        file_name="file${file_number}.txt"
        content="$file_name     $data"
        #echo $content
        echo $content >> result.csv
done
```

`result.csv` file contains the expected result.

**EDIT: The following code is better**

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=/path/to/directory
for file in $FILES
do
        data=$( cat $file | cut -f1 -d' ' | cut -f8 -d'_' | tr '\n' '\t' )
        content="$file  $data"
        echo $content >> result.csv
done
```

**Explanation**

`FILES` contains all the input files.
Using `cut` command we get the field (which contains the float number).
Using `tr` we replace the tabs to new lines.
`result.csv` file contains your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk (extended command):

```
awk -F '[ _]' '
               /^[^ ]*_[^ _]* /{
                                 a[FILENAME]=a[FILENAME] " " $(NF-1)
                               }
               END{
                   for(i in a){print i,a[i]}
                  }
              ' Filename*
```

May be executed as a one liner:

```
$ awk -F '[ _]' '/^[^ ]*_[^ _]* /{a[FILENAME]=a[FILENAME] " " $(NF-1)}END{for(i in a){print i,a[i]}}' Filename*

Filename1   60.3    37.2    0.6
Filename2   56.1    26.2    52.3
```